# Git: How to find out when a Tag is created?

Tags: git, tags

How can I find out when a specific Tag was created? I can see the date of the last commit in that Tag but how to get the date when the Tag was created? For example, if the last commit was done on Jul 15 and Tag was created on Jul 17 then how can I find out the Jul 17 date?

Answer (score 3):

```
git show --format=fuller <tag> | grep -F TaggerDate:
git for-each-ref --format='%(taggerdate)' refs/tags/<tag>
```

where `<tag>` is the placeholder for a tag.

Please note this only work  for annotated tags and don't work for lightweight tags. Lightweight tags are simple references — only name and commit ID. Annotated or signed tags are Git database objects, they contains more metadata — tagger name, tagger email, tagger date, signature.

Comment: “Please note this only work for annotated tags and don't work for lightweight tags.”—Although you can set `core.logAllRefUpdates = always` and get the time from the reflog (for future lightweight tag creations). With all the reflog caveats and limitations.